# Is dandelion a sporophyte or gametophyte?

Tags: botany, sexual-reproduction, pollination

My text book claims all land plants undergo alternation of generation. However, I don't see how it could be with dandelion. The flower head gets pollinated and then turn back on itself. After a while it opens back as a seed head ready to blow seed in the wind. What would be the spores then? And the gametophyte organism? All seeds are a result of sperm and ovula so it would mean the dandelion flower is a sporophyte?

Comment: See [Alternation of generations - Life cycles of different plant groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternation_of_generations#Life_cycles_of_different_plant_groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dandelions are sporothytes. In Wikipedia you can read ([Alternation of generations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternation_of_generations)):

> "In the spermatophytes, the seed plants, the sporophyte is the
>   dominant multicellular phase; the gametophytes are strongly reduced in
>   size and very different in morphology. The entire gametophyte
>   generation, with the sole exception of pollen grains
>   (microgametophytes), is contained within the sporophyte. The life
>   cycle of a dioecious flowering plant (angiosperm), the willow, has
>   been outlined in some detail in an earlier section (A complex life
>   cycle). The life cycle of a gymnosperm is similar. However, flowering
>   plants have in addition a phenomenon called 'double fertilization'.
>   Two sperm nuclei from a pollen grain (the microgametophyte), rather
>   than a single sperm, enter the archegonium of the megagametophyte; one
>   fuses with the egg nucleus to form the zygote, the other fuses with
>   two other nuclei of the gametophyte to form 'endosperm', which
>   nourishes the developing embryo. For further information, see Double
>   fertilization"

Comment: Hi @Olga. Welcome, and thanks for contributing to Bio.SE! Generally, we ask that answers don't simply include large quoted blocks of text, and instead we hope that those that answer expand upon the resources (quotes, pictures, links) that they provide with additional context, backround, etc. Your post will likely garner more positive attention if you expand upon it further. Additionally, if you reference or quote something specifically, please provide a direct link to where the quote arises so interested users may explore the topic further. Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Thank you for constructive comments (my English is not very well and that's why I decided to take such a long quote). For the future I will try to try harder :-). Have a nice day..